# flutter variable is not passing in class widget

Tags: flutter, class, variables

How to pass variable declared to class widget.
It is showing error "undefined name abcd".
But I have already declared it.
How to pass this variable abcd in Text widget.
Code is attached.
Thanks in advance.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final String abcd = "abcd";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(),
            OkButton(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OkButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text("ok"),
          ),
          Text(abcd),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to add a [constructor](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors) to pass a variable from a class to another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass your value from one `class` to another by using `Constructor`

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final String abcd = "abcd";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(),
            OkButton(abcd),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OkButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String abcd;
  OkButton(this.abcd);
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text("ok"),
          ),
          Text(abcd),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a constructor in the `OkButton` which accepts a `String`.

```
class OkButton extends StatelessWidget {
  OkButton({@required this.text});

  final String text;

  ...
    Text(text), // from Text(abcd),
  ...
}
```

Then, when you create `OkButton`, set the `text` property.

```
OkButton(text: abcd),
```

Comment: yup, this is a good answer. but if you don't want it to mandatory just get rid of that @required. and if only 1 parameter I suggest not using a bracket, so it can be more compact like this OkButton(abcd),.